# How to make a button float over layout like a FAB, or make one FAB with double button?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, material-design

[image]

The button at the bottom, Map/filter. It's from the expedia app. What kind of button is it? Can a FAB be overriden to have two button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess, as someone who has made an *extremely* similar widget myself, is that this is neither a FAB nor even a Button at all. It's probably just a floating ViewGroup with two clickable areas (maybe a LinearLayout holding two TextViews, for instance).

You create it by using a `FrameLayout` (or spiritual subclass like `CoordinatorLayout`) to host your main content view, and then your "button" view group on top of that. `CardView` is a great way to get rounded corners and elevation on all Android API levels:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- insert your content here -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_map"
                android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                android:textColor="#00f"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/label_map"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:background="#ccc"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_filters"
                android:drawablePadding="6dp"
                android:textColor="#00f"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/label_filters"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]